# Conditional return type not understood by compiler

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

i did some searching but couldn't find anything conclusive to my problem. Sorry if this is a duplicate, I'll be glad if you redirect me.

My issue is that I wrote a store class for the project I'm working on. Which has a function like this:

```js
public getStore(store: 'FIELD1' | 'FIELD2'): State<typeof store> {
 return this[store];
}
```

with the corresponding conditional type in the file:

```js
export type State<T> = T extends 'FIELD1'
  ? Field1Type[]
  : T extends 'FIELD2'
  ? Date
  : never;
```

I expected this should result in fixing the compile message that the return can be `Field1Type[] | Date`, when I write `getStore('FIELD1').length`. But it doesn't.

This is inconvenient for me because I'm writing an Angular app and wanted to call this in the component's HTML, without needing a helper in the component's script.

Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently written, your method returns a union of `Date | Field1Type[]`. The union type implies that the method could return either a `Date` or `Field1Type[]` disregarding the input, so accessing the `length` property is not allowed.

You should consider using [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to correlate the return type with the input:

```
getStore(store: 'FIELD1'): Field1Type[] 
getStore(store: 'FIELD2'): Date
getStore(store: 'FIELD1' | 'FIELD2'): Date | Field1Type[] {
 return this[store];
}
```

You can also use your generic type `State` here if you depend on its implementation.

```
getStore<T extends 'FIELD1' | 'FIELD2'>(store: T): State<T>
getStore(store: 'FIELD1' | 'FIELD2'): Date | Field1Type[] {
 return this[store];
}

export type State<T> = T extends 'FIELD1'
  ? Field1Type[]
  : T extends 'FIELD2'
  ? Date
  : never;
```

You should also consider replacing your implementation of `State` with a simpler map-like structure:

```
export type State<T extends string> = ({
  FIELD1: Field1Type[]
  FIELD2: Date
} & Record<string, never>)[T]
```

Comment: The overload works! Could have thought of that... Thanks. Any way to make it simpler maybe? This store is probably not going to grow much. But I have another that already has 5 states to manage and may get even more later. So this could result in quite an unreadable overload mess.

Comment: @dscham - Sure, you could always use a single overload which uses some generic type as its return type (as shown in the second code block). I would recommend swapping the conditionals inside State with a map-like structure as shown here: https://tsplay.dev/WKPyow

Comment: I would add, you can put the symbol union in a type as well: `type Store = 'SYMBOL1' | 'SYMBOL2' | ...`. Now I think this is a really nice solution. Only having to define the field and the symbol for it. Using the Store type wherever you duplicated the union before and the new store is ready to go.